# Singly linked list in Java - get() method

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Java and trying to implement a singly linked list in Java. I have included the use of generics. The code is shown below:

```
public class LinkedListX<E>{

   Node <E> head;
   int size;

   LinkedListX(){
       head = null;
       size = 0;
   }

   LinkedListX (E e){
       head = new Node(e);
       size = 1;
   }

   void add(E e){
       if (head == null){
           head = new Node (e);
       } else {
           Node current = this.head;
           while (current.next != null){
               current = current.next;
           }
           current.next = new Node(e);
       }
       size++;
   }

   E get (int n){
       if (n > size){
           return null;
       }
       Node current = head;
       for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
           current = current.next;
       }
       return current.e;
   }

   private class Node<E> {
       private E e;
       private Node next;

       Node (E e, Node n){
           this.e = e;
           this.next = n;
       }
       Node (E e) {
           this.e = e;
       }
   }
```

}

the `get()` method gives error message

> Incompatible types, Require:E, Found: java.lang.Object" at "return
>   current.e

I think I am using generics in a wrong way. Could someone let me know the right way to code this method?

Thanks.

Comment: `Node current = head;` > `Node<E> current = head;`

Comment: Read up on generics in general and raw types/type erasure in particular. That should clarify things.

Comment: On a side note: Since your Node class is a private nested class and it's only purpose beeing to wrap the value into a common object you can omit the generic from it and still use the enclosing classes type parameter `E`

Answer (score 5):

As `Node` is an inner class it can also access the outer classes generic parameter. And you never assign a different value to `E` than the one from the outer class. So just remove the `<E>` from `Node` class declaration:

```
private class Node{
    // the rest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing a `Node` as `next` without using its generic attributes - there are various places where you should be using `Node<E>` instead of just `Node`.

The problem basically is that you try to return `E`, but you save `Node` which is mapped by the compiler to `Node<Object>` - and `Object` isn't `E`

Answer (score 1):

To use correctly generic, you may change :

- in `get()` : `Node current = head;`to `Node<E> current = head;`
- all your `new Node()` to `new Node<>()` (shortcut for `new Node<E>()`
- in `Node` class use also `<E>`

---

You can also just remove the `<E>` from all your `Node` (to all the Node class), you will still be able to use `E` for the data)

Answer (score 1):

You mix two problems:

1. This line causes the problem (4 lines above the type mismatch):

   ```
   Node current = head;
   ```

   You have to include generics as well, otherwise, its raw type is recognized as `Object`.

   ```
   Node<E> current = head;
   ```

   Once you use a generic object, always include its type with `<>`.
2. The second thing is that you already use generics on the outer class `LinkedListX <E>` thus all its inner work with the `E` parameter. For this, the generics within the `Node` class can be omitted.

   ```
   private class Node { 

       // the implementation
   }
   ```

   Otherwise, the warning complaint appears:

   > The type parameter E is hiding the type E

Answer (score 1):

```
Node current = head;
```

The above line is a raw type declaration, and in such case 'java.lang.Object' is the default Type Variable.

Using a parameterised type Node  `Node<E> current = head;` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of raw references of Node which is generating a lot of warnings . In your `get(int n)` snippet `Node` is raw and not generic so Java type inference algorithm failed to identify it as  E and considering its as an Object. Please use the below code and check the difference in Eclipse

```
public class LinkedListX<E> {

    Node<E> head;
    int size;

    LinkedListX() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    LinkedListX(E e) {
        head = new Node<E>(e);
        size = 1;
    }

    void add(E e) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node<E>(e);
        } else {
            Node<E> current = this.head;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = new Node<E>(e);
        }
        size++;
    }

    E get(int n) {
        if (n > size) {
            return null;
        }
        Node<E> current = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current.e;
    }

    static private class Node<E> {
        private E e;
        private Node<E> next;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
            this.e = e;
            this.next = n;
        }

        Node(E e) {
            this.e = e;
        }
    }
}
```